# Array subsetting in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

With the Julia Language, I defined a function to sample points uniformly inside the sphere of radius 3.14 using rejection sampling as follows:

```
function spherical_sample(N::Int64)

    # generate N points uniformly distributed inside sphere 
    # using rejection sampling:

    points = pi*(2*rand(5*N,3).-1.0)

    ind = sum(points.^2,dims=2) .<= pi^2

    ## ideally I wouldn't have to do this: 
    ind_ = dropdims(ind,dims=2)

    return points[ind_,:][1:N,:]

end
```

I found a hack for subsetting arrays:

```
ind = sum(points.^2,dims=2) .<= pi^2

## ideally I wouldn't have to do this: 
ind_ = dropdims(ind,dims=2)
```

But, in principle array indexing should be a one-liner. How could I do this better in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a 2-dimensional index vector. You can avoid it by using `eachrow`:

```
ind = sum.(eachrow(points.^2)) .<= pi^2
```

So that your full answer would be:

```
function spherical_sample(N::Int64)
    points = pi*(2*rand(5*N,3).-1.0)
    ind = sum.(eachrow(points.^2)) .<= pi^2
    return points[ind,:][1:N,:]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner:

```
points[(sum(points.^2,dims=2) .<= pi^2)[:],:][1:N, :]
```

Note that `[:]` is dropping a dimension so the `BitArray` can be used for indexing.

Comment: In this answer, and similar in David's, it would be better to take first `N` elements from `ind` like `sum(x->x^2, points, dims=2) .<= pi^2)[1:N]` (it would also drop a dimension and at the same avoid excessive allocation of a temporary matrix). Still it is not guaranteed that `ind` has `N` elements so this will often produce an error - see my comment below.

Comment: `(sum(x->x^2, points, dims=2) .<= pi^2)[1:N]` does not help because this is the selection vector so it needs to contain more than N elements (and anyway can fail sometimes).

Comment: Agreed - this is what I have written in my comment.

Answer (score 4):

This does not answer your question directly (as you already got two suggestions), but I rather thought to hint how you could implement the whole procedure differently if you want it to be efficient.

The first point is to avoid generating `5*N` rows of data - the problem is that it is very likely that it will be not enough to generate `N` valid samples. The point is that the probability of a valid sample in your model is ~50%, so it is possible that there will not be enough points to choose from and `[1:N, :]` selection will throw an error.

Below is the code I would use that avoids this problem:

```
function spherical_sample(N::Integer) # no need to require Int64 only here
    points = 2 .* pi .* rand(N, 3) .- 1.0 # note that all operations are vectorized to avoid excessive allocations
    while N > 0 # we will run the code until we have N valid rows
        v = @view points[N, :] # use view to avoid allocating
        if sum(x -> x^2, v) <= pi^2 # sum accepts a transformation function as a first argument
            N -= 1 # row is valid - move to the previous one
        else
            rand!(v) # row is invalid - resample it in place
            @. v = 2 * pi * v - 1.0 # again - do the computation in place via broadcasting
        end
    end
    return points
end
```

Comment: How did you get 19.7%? Actually, if I use just one row of data the probability is close to 50% since I am sampling points from [-pi,pi]^3 , the sphere has volume 4/3*pi*r^3 ≈ 4*r^3 and the cube has volume 8*r^3 so vol(sphere)/vol(cube)≈4/8=50%.

Comment: Right - I must have mistyped something. It is around 50%. Still with `N=5` I was constantly getting errors when I run `@benchmark` of your function as the probability of not finding enough valid points was high.

Comment: In my use case N is always greater than or equal to 10 and since vol(sphere)/vol(cube)≈50% we can model our samples as a binomial random variable and the probability of observing less than 10  heads in 50 tosses is less than 3 in a million.

Answer (score 3):

This one is pretty fast, and uses StaticArrays. You can probably also implement something similar with ordinary tuples:

```
using StaticArrays

function sphsample(N)
    T = SVector{3, Float64}
    v = Vector{T}(undef, N)
    n = 1
    while n <= N
        p = rand(T) .- 0.5
        @inbounds v[n] = p .* 2π
        n += (sum(abs2, p) <= 0.25)
    end
    return v
end
```

On my laptop it is ~9x faster than the solution with `view`s.